# Angular 2 Http.Post not sending request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Trying to make a simple POST to my server, with some data and have it return some JSON data. (Currently, it runs through the call but I see nothing on my network tab that it actually tried to make it?)

My Service (api.service.ts)

```js
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

 private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
   private myUrl = 'https://www.mywebsite.com';  // URL to web api
   private payLoad = {"thingy1":"Value1", "thingy2":"value2"};

   constructor(private http:Http) { }

   getData () {
        this.http.post(this.myUrl, JSON.stringify(this.payLoad), this.headers)
         .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    } 

}
```

Then I just have the getData method ran in a header component just to fire it. 
(header.component.ts)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

//Service
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:ApiService) { 
    this.service.getData(); //Fire getData from api.service
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Observable are lazy, even if you initialize them, they will not be executed. At least one subscriber has to explicitly `subscribe` to that observable to listen to that stream. In short: They will only be executed when you subscribe to it.

```
this.service.getData().subscribe(
  (data) => console.log(data)
);
```

Comment: This did it, I of course had to add return to the getData method. Man... Seriously been screwing with this all day. Don't know why I just come to stack first.. Thanks Alot!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are subscribing your observable data. The RxJS observer has 2 parts,

- next() - it push data which is done by angular itself.
- subscribe -  you need in your component to get data from observable.

Try something below

```
this.service.getData().subscribe(
  (data) => {
   //process your data here
  }
);
```

Comment: how to get data out of observable and send again as observable. once we subscribe, the return type changes.

Comment: You can use .map()  and then return. it will get the data and hold return type observable.